world_clim funtion in bioclim package can not deliver worldclim "bio" variables from Russia
Trying to download worldclim "bio" variables from Russia using bioclim package but are getting errors (see below). Doing the same thing for other countries such as Sweden, Norway, Georgia and Spain works just as it should, but not for Russia. Downloading other worldcim variables such as "tmin" seems to be working as it should even for Russia.
Anyone have an idea why "bio" variables from russia isnt downloading?

Biodata_russia <- worldclim_country("russia", var = "bio", path=tempdir())

Error: [rast] cannot open this file as a SpatRaster: C:/Users/peax/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiaYK6d/climate/wc2.1_country/RUS_wc2.1_30s_bio.tif
In addition: Warning message:
`C:/Users/peax/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpiaYK6d/climate/wc2.1_country/RUS_wc2.1_30s_bio.tif' not recognized as a supported file format. (GDAL error 4)

By using worldclim_global funtion I was able to get all data. I have not figured out why downloading russia did not work

I would recommend using the worldclim_country function in the geodata library. It is a much more current package and is updated frequently (from the developers of terra whom also published the worldclim dataset). The last update to the bioclim package was 3 years ago as opposed to 3 months ago for geodata.
